# How do i create a template class with specialized functions created in base classes?

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry if my description is not very clear. What i want to do is the following:

```
template <typename T>
class SubContainer
{
public:
    
    void add(T item)
    {
        mVector.push_back(item);
    }
    
private:
    std::vector<T> mVector;
};

class Container
    : public SubContainer<int>
    , public SubContainer<float>
{
};

int main()
{
    Container container;
    container.add<int>(1);
    container.add<float>(2.0);
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work. I've tried making add a nested template, and using enable_if to only enable for instance `SubContainer<int>::add<int>()`, but i did not get it working properly.

Furthermore, i would like to define the container as `Container<int, float> container;`. I've seen that this likely requires using tuples, but again i did not get it to compile.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you might find this link useful for your question. https://youtu.be/vZPkYvsqQxQ

Comment: You want call explicating the template parameter (so with the `<int>` part in `.add<int>(1)`) or is OK, for you, template deduction (so also `add(1)` is OK)?

Comment: You can get it to compile with `container.SubContainer<int>::add(1);` but you should explain what the actual problem is that you want to solve, since this is probably not the right way to go about it.

Comment: @dxiv I would like to hide the SubComponent class from the user of the class, as he should not be required to know how the container works internally in order to put something in it. This is the start of an entity system, so it will (hopefully) grow more complex.

Comment: @max66 In my usecase, explicitly declaring the template parameter would be preferable, mostly because i want to avoid implicit conversions.

Comment: @Victor - So the second part of my answer should be useful for you, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Furthermore, i would like to define the container as `Container<int, float> container;`.

It seems to me that your looking for a variadic template class as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class Container : public SubContainer<Ts>...
 {
   public:
      using SubContainer<Ts>::add...;
 };
```

so you can write

```
Container<int, float> container;
container.add(1);
container.add(2.0f);
```

but this way you obtain the right `add()` through template deduction, not explicating the template parameter.

If you want to explicate the template parameter, you can explicitly call the right base class, as suggested by dixv in a comment

```
container.SubContainer<int>::add(1);
```

or you can pass through a template class wrapper as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class Container : public SubContainer<Ts>...
 {
   public:
      template <typename T>
      void add (T item)
       { SubContainer<T>::add(item); }
 };
```

so you can both use the template deduction

```
container.add(1);
container.add(2.0f);
```

or explicating the template parameter

```
container.add<int>(1);
container.add<float>(2.0f);
```